# Magento 2 - How to Change Shipping information in one page checkout - payment step

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.2.6

I created one shipping method for store pickup. Its working fine.

But i need to change the **shipping information(i.e address)** as store address but it should not affect the `customer_address table data`.

What exactly i need is to change the address before submitting shipping address from shipping method step to payment step.
In below picture shipping info should contains store address

[image]

**I'm working in magento 2.26 version.**

**Thank you**

Comment: you can override shipping information address renderer template

Comment: Can u give idea how to do that. because it returing customer data @magefms

Answer (score 0):

I got answer. I used **extension_attribute** for passing store address. this extension attributes can be accessible in shipping information address renderer template.

So i override the **shipping information** address renderer template